# Unit norm eigenvectors of a symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

I read the following in a paper and I have a hard time understanding it.

> ... unit norm eigenvector are at most defined upto a single sign flip and we have to choose the signs synchonously.

What does "unit norm eigenvectors are defined unto a single sign flip" mean?  Does it mean that "if $v_i$ is an eigenvector then $-v_i$ is also an eigenvector?

Answer (score 1):

You're right: "if $v_i$ is an eigenvector then $−v_i$ is also an eigenvector".

Indeed, eigenvectors of a matrix $A$ are specified by 
$$
A v_i = \lambda_i v_i
$$ 
with eigenvalues $\lambda_i$. So with any constant $c$, $c v_i$  also satisfies the equation.

It is usual to choose $c = d/|v_i|$ with $|d| = 1$ so you have unit norm eigenvectors. However, this still leaves you the choice of $d$  with $|d| = 1$. Not only can you choose $d = \pm 1$, but also complex values with norm 1, in case the solutions are not real.

Comment: There's something more. It is probably the case that all eigenvalues are distinct, so all eigenspaces are one dimensional. In a one dimensional real vector space there are only two vectors of norm $1$.